# Proper Way to Start Unit Testing a Web API

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I need to start testing a Web API, for now I'm going to start with unit tests and I can't figure out the right way to do it. Here is what I have in mind doing:

The API consists on a list of endpoints that authenticated users can access. My intention is, for each endpoint, write a unit test that checks:

- Status code is the expected one
- Response is a valid JSON response
- Actual response is the expected one

Is it okay to test multiple things in a single unit test?

All the endpoints have multiple parameters and I think that writing a single unit test for each endpoint would be too long for a unit test (because I'll have to test each parameter works fine), so I thought of creating multiple tests, one for each parameter tested, do you think this is a good idea?.

I would like to know also if there is anything you would unit test in an API apart from the three things listed before, my idea is to test that what the user gets is the expected output, from there I will start unit testing the functions used internally for the API.

Comment: What you are proposing is to write integration tests. A unit test typically runs in-process and does not access any outside resources. To write unit tests at this level implies that all file system, database calls and web service calls will be mocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it okay to test multiple things in a single unit test?

That depends on what you mean with "multiple things". A test case should verify only a single "thing", but if the thing that you want to verify is "the response from my API", then it can take multiple checks/assert statements to verify that the response you received is the one you expected. But that is still just a single thing.

On the other hand, you are verifying multiple things if your one test case covers both a successful call to your API and one or more failed calls.

> so I thought of creating multiple tests, one for each parameter tested, do you think this is a good idea?

Yes. Definitely.
Besides a test with correct values, you should have separate tests for each way that a parameter (or combination of parameters) can be specified incorrectly. That way, you are ensured that when you introduce a bug that breaks the system in multiple ways, that you get to know them all, rather than the only first one that causes your test to report a failure.